# Angular JS drag and drop DataUrl not triggering ng-show

Tags: javascript, angularjs, drag-and-drop, filereader

I want angular to trigger ng-show once I read the file that I am dragging and dropping so it will output the file as an image with the source as a dataUrl. I need to be able to read the file locally prior to upload in order for my app to work properly.  I test all my event handlers dragenter, dragover, drop, they are all firing, I am setting a $scope.dataUrl variable with $scope.setDataUrl function and its firing but ng-show still won't evaluate the variable and show the div. I had alot of validation for the image format and etc... but for the sake of simplicity I removed it so I can get at the problem with the variable. d

do I need to use a route, or use the factory method to share it with another object for the event to fire and the div to be shown?

Here is my index file

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html ng-app="myApp">
   <head>
      <title></title>
       <script src="Scripts/angular-1.0.7.min.js"></script>
       <script src="app/dd.js"></script>
       <style>

           html, body { height:100%; background-color:#e3e3e3; }

       </style>
   </head>
   <body dd="">
        <div ng-show="dataUrl">

             dataUrl is defined!

        </div>
    </body>
 </html>
```

here is my script file (app/dd.js)
      var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

```
  function myController($scope, $http) {

     $scope.dataUrl = null;

     $scope.setDataUrl = function (data) {

              $scope.dataUrl = data;
              console.log($scope.dataUrl);
     }

   }


   app.directive('dd', function () {

      return {

          restrict: "A",
          controller:"myController",
          link: function (scope, element, attr, ddCtrl) {

             function handleDragEnter(e) {

              console.log('dragEventer function');

        }

        function handleDragOver(e) {

            console.log('dragOver function');
            e.preventDefault();
            e.stopPropagation();
            e.dataTransfer.dropEffect = "copy";
        }

        function handleDrop(e) {


            e.preventDefault();
            e.stopPropagation();
            var files = e.dataTransfer.files;
            var file = files[0];

            console.log(file);
            var reader = new FileReader();

            reader.onload = function (e) {

               var data =  e.target.result;
               scope.setDataUrl(data);

            }

            reader.readAsDataURL(file);
        }



           element.bind('dragenter', handleDragEnter);
           element.bind('dragover', handleDragOver);
           element.bind('drop', handleDrop);


       }

    }

  });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `scope`'s [`$apply`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24rootScope.Scope#%24apply) method:

```
$scope.$apply(function(){
   $scope.dataUrl = data;
});
```

Comment: OK it worked! thanks! If I may ask why did that work? the $apply method what does it do? the reason I ask is because I want to use it later on to trigger the $routeProvider to load another partial? can that be done the same way?

Comment: @Jesse you have to use `apply` after every *async* step. here you have an explanation from Angular' creator: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9682092/databinding-in-angularjs/9693933#9693933